# How to replace value in string except last occurrence of specific value in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, replace

Assume that i have this column value:

`new operational goods123 type 1 for main goods type 9`

I want to get value of digit after last occurrence of **type** word with replace and using regular expression.
In this case i want to find **9**.
I think that regular expression maybe something like this:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE((SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(' new operational goods123 type 1 for main goods type 2 ',
                                            '[^(type)[:digit:]]',
                                            ' ')
                        FROM dual),
                      '[^[:digit:]]')
  from dual;
```

but this query returns **12319**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('new operational goods123 type 1 for main goods type 9',
                      '.*type\s*([0-9]+).*',
                      '\1',
                      1,
                      1,
                      'n'
                     ) as Result from dual
```

[image]

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/LCW45717)

The pattern matches

- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible (including newlines as `n` modifier is used)
- `type` - the last occurrence of `type` in string (due to the preceding greedy pattern)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `([0-9]+)` - 1 or more digits *captured into Group 1*
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

The replacement contains a `\1` placeholder referencing the value in Group 1.

The first `1` is the starting position for the search engine and the second `1` is the "the occurrence of the replace operation" (we need to replace only once).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select substr('new operational goods123 type 1 for main goods type 9', instr('new operational goods123 type 1 for main goods type 9', 'type', -1)+ 5) from dual
```

Note: I have assumed there is a space after "type"